# Access OpenShift web console remotely

Tags: kubernetes, console, openshift, istio

I have a headless CentOS 7 box to which I have `ssh` access. I have installed OpenShift v4.2 - the [Code Ready Containers](https://code-ready.github.io/crc/) version successfully. I am able to use the `oc` tool, create projects, access exposed routes from services, etc.

I want to explore the visualization that comes from Istio - the service mesh. How do I access the web console remotely so that I can explore the service mesh?

[Katacoda](https://2886795330-8443-simba02.environments.katacoda.com) does not seem to have a OpenShift 4.2 cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to my mind for the more generic case of connecting to a remote GUI:

- VNC tunneled over ssh
- X11 forwarding using ssh

Some years ago, VNC worked way better for me - it was lighter-weight and faster.

Comment: On VNC, did you mean this? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-remote-access-for-the-gnome-desktop-on-centos-7

Comment: That seems to be helpful for installing VNC server and client, and configuring them on CentOS 7. For the ssh part, googling for `vnc ssh` returns results that can help. A glance over https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-vnc-using-ssh/ appears to have step-by-step setup if VNC server is already installed.

Comment: I will look into the article you pasted. What's the advantage of vnc over ssh, primarily facie.?

Comment: The answers to this question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/differences-between-vnc-and-ssh-x - and some of the comments, I think, provide good info (X Window System is the same as X11)